# How to escape default behaviour of Medoo table prefixing in Select query with joining

Tags: php, mysql, medoo

I want to replicate this MySQL query in medoo framework in PHP

```
SELECT col1,col2
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
  ON t1.col1 = t2.col4 AND t1.col2=1;
```

This is what i can come up with

```
$database->select("table1",[
   "[>]table2"=>["col1"=>"col4","col2"=>1]
],[
   "col1","col2"
]);
```

But this results in the query

```
SELECT col1,col2 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
  ON table1.col1=table2.col4 
 AND table1.col2=table2.1
```

So is there a way I can escape the default table prefixing by Medoo. I've tried adding a '#' before the column  just like in SQL functions but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea - what about to use the second condition in WHERE clausule?

Comment: Those would then be 2 different queries and the results are different too